# Intermittent "working-in-background cursor" in Windows

Tags: windows, mouse-cursor

I work on both a new Windows 10 machine (i7-7700) and a 7-year-old machine running Windows 7 (i3-3225).  Both have 16GB RAM, SSD primary drives, and task manager shows plenty of CPU and memory free.

But on both machines a "busy" circle intermittently flashes next to my mouse cursor.  On the Windows 10 machine, if I have no foreground activity, it's at least once every six seconds.  Just for an instant it goes from regular pointer to this:

[image: Windows background busy cursor]

Of course I have a ton of services and background processes running.

But I don't care so much *why* the O/S is flashing that cursor at me with irritating regularity; I just want to stop seeing it because it has become extremely distracting.

So it might be great if I could find and kill whatever processes are causing it.

But I might be happier if I could, for example, replace the "background busy" cursor with the standard cursor so I never see it.  (I.e., "OK, computer, I get that you've got a lot going on.  Just keep it to yourself; I'm trying to work here!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the default cursors easily. For Windows 10:

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type "mouse".
- Select *Change your mouse settings*.
- Select the *Pointers* tab.

[image: Mouse Cursor Settings]

- Click the *Browse* button.
- Select another cursor.

You might want to pick (or create) a cursor that is identical to the standard, but with a few pixels different, to give you *some* indication that the machine is a bit busy.

For Windows 7, open the Mouse CPL.

See [Digital Trends](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-pointer-windows/) for more information.

You might try leaving open the *Details* tab in Task Manager, ordering by CPU usage, and change *Update speed* to *High* to help find the nuisance process.

Comment: Excellent!  I've tried running the task manager, ordered by CPU, at High Update, but the "background-busy" cursor flash occurs much more quickly than the High speed updates, so I just don't see anything weird popping up or corresponding to the cursor flash in the process list even after watching it for a while....